# Begin a new paragraph in email body

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, text

I have a Google Sheet containing some data that I've pulled into the body of an email (i.e., the message line in the code shown below).  However, I want to insert a new paragraph beginning with `studentName` and another new paragraph beginning with `sessionName`.  Tried `\r\n` and `<br/>` but can't get either to work.  To be clear, I want the final email to look like this:

> Subject:
>
> Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt
>
> Body:
>
> This confirms your registration.  Your credit card has been charged
> $0.00.
>
> Student Name: John Doe
>
> Session(s):  May - Session 1

```
function SendEmail() {
 // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
var studentRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C2");
var studentName = studentRange.getValues();
var sessionRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("D2");
var sessionName = sessionRange.getValues();
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
var ChgAmt = Browser.inputBox("Charge Amount");

// Send Alert Email.
var subject = 'Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt';
var message = 'This confirms your registration.  Your credit card has been charged '+ ChgAmt + <br/> + studentName + sessionName ; // Second column

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
  
}
```

Comment: What about `'+ ChgAmt + '<br/>' + studentName` concatenate the strings and vars using + and '' (untested)

Comment: If that works I would just insert opening and closing paragraph tags  `'<p>' +var+ '</p> Some string'`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get any of those suggestions to work.  Here again is the line of code I'm trying to separate.  I wnat the credit card charged amount in paragragh 1, the student's name in paragraph 2 and the session names in paragraph 3.  ~var message = 'This confirms your registration.  Your credit card has been charged: '+ ChgAmt + 'Student Name: ' + studentName + 'Session(s): '+ sessionName~~

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to use Google Apps Script.
- You want to add the line break to the text body of email.

From your question, I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- You can retrieve the values of `B2:D2` by one request. By this, the process cost will be able to be reduced.
- In order to add the line break to the text body, you can use `\n` as the line break. You can also use `\r\n`.

  - I coudln't see the script about `Tried \r\n and but can't get either to work.`. So I directly modified your script.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function SendEmail() {
  // Fetch the email address
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2:D2").getValues()[0];
  var emailAddress = values[0];
  var studentName = values[1];
  var sessionName = values[2];
  var ChgAmt = Browser.inputBox("Charge Amount");

  var lineBreak = '\n'; // or \r\n

  // Send Alert Email.
  var subject = 'Junior Golf Clinic Registration Receipt';
  var message = 'This confirms your registration.  Your credit card has been charged ' + ChgAmt + lineBreak +
  'Student Name: ' + studentName + lineBreak +
  'Session(s): ' + sessionName;

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. And I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create new paragraph elements (and assign them to constants for easier access to them in the next steps)

```
const para1 = document.createElement('p');
const para2 = document.createElement('p');
```

2.Put some text in your paragraphs

```
para1.textContent = "Student Name:" + studentname;
para2.textContent = "Session(s):" + sessionName;
```

3.Append your paragraphs to the parent element. This can vary depending on your html structure, but this code is assuming the element in which you want your paragraphs to be has ID "emailContainer"

```
document.getElementById("emailContainer").appendChild(para1);
document.getElementById("emailContainer").appendChild(para2);
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm just too new Javascript to understand how to do what you are asking.  Using my original code shown above, can you show me how these pieces fit together?  Thanks.